# JavaScript and Styles compression

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, compression, minify

I understand the basic principles of script/style compression.  What I would like to know is how do I integrate minified/combined scripts into my process and not interrupt my normal development flow?

I obviously want to use the regular files while developing then switch to the minified versions for deployment.  I currently use [YepNope](http://yepnopejs.com/) to load my scripts.  Is there some sort of conditional I could use to tell the browser to load the regular files?

Environment: VS 2010

Comment: You may checkout [Combres](http://combres.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this was to go with Microsoft's own [Ajax Min](http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/) its pretty nice.  Compression is on par with some others I used.

As far as telling the browser to load minified versions or full, I added that into the post build script. Basically if you are in this particular environment then do not build the minified versions.  Then in the js I have a little flag that points to one or the other depending on environment.

Hope this helps.